# Package to indent and syntax highlight C++ code

Tags: packages, listings, minted

I am looking for a package to have an environment for C++ source code, with options for syntax highlighting, automatic indentation, proper multipage behavior, etc.

I read something about the listings package but I guess there is already a good solution to my problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`listings`](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/listings) is the de facto standard for source code inclusion. It supports highlighting and its multipage behaviour should be alright.

Another option is [`minted`](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/minted), it is a bit harder to use but more powerful. You do get dependent on external software though (Pygments), it's not as cross-platform as just using a package.

Why do you want automatic indentation? I assume you are inputting existing files, they already should have good indentation according to a standard. It is a lot harder to accomplish this in a package, you'd have to write a full-blown parser for your language of choice and support all different indentation schemes, maybe Pygments can help you there, but I have never heard of this behaviour in TeX before.

Comment: OK, you make me realize that I don't need auto indentation ... I'll have a look at `listings`.

Comment: If you really need auto indentation, you could always run the code through a C++ indenter before including it into your TeX.