# How to format a block of source code?

Tags: formatting, sourcecode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Package to indent and syntax highlight C++ code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4799/package-to-indent-and-syntax-highlight-c-code)

I want to format a block of C source code using TeX, how can I accomplish this work?

for example:

```c
int main()
{
    printf( "Hello World!\n" );

    return 1;
}
```

I wish to format the source code of mine like tex.stackexchange.

Comment: Maybe you can find your answer here : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4799/package-to-indent-and-syntax-highlight-c-code

Comment: As per http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/closing-questions-as-exact-duplications-best-practice, we should give @UniMouS a chance to come back on this before closing :-)